# Using def function to call image from urllib import urlopen - python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib, urlopen

I have made def function to call JPG image to display easily but it in not working property. Also I don't want to use urllib2. It says image_file = image_to_PhotoImage(image)
NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Any suggestions? Thank you

```
from urllib import urlopen
from Tkinter import *

def image_to_PhotoImage(image, width = None, height = None):

    # Import the Python Imaging Library, if it exists
    try:
        from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    except:
        raise Exception, 'Python Imaging Library has not been installed properly!'

    # Import StringIO for character conversions
    from StringIO import StringIO

    # Convert the raw bytes into characters
    image_chars = StringIO(image)

    # Open the character string as a PIL image, if possible
    try:
        pil_image = Image.open(image_chars)
    except:
        raise Exception, 'Cannot recognise image given to "image_to_Photoimage" function\n' + \
                         'Confirm that image was downloaded correctly'

    # Resize the image, if a new size has been provided
    if type(width) == int and type(height) == int and width > 0 and height > 0:
        pil_image = pil_image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Return the result as a Tkinter PhotoImage
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)


import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

url = "http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"
gogo = urlopen(url)

data_stream = gogo.read()
gogo.close()

image_file = image_to_PhotoImage(image1)
label = tk.Label(root, image=image_file, bg='black')
```

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: It give me error like image_file = image_to_PhotoImage(image) NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Comment: Well, `image` and `image1` don't exist. Why do you think it should do something different? Why do you think one of  those variables xist?

Comment: variable `image1` is not defined.`image_file = image_to_PhotoImage(data_stream)` solve the problem ?

Comment: So to call image_to_PhotoImage( function what do I have to name the image output as? or is something wrong with my def?